# How to find out windows form controls inside infragistics Tab Control?

Tags: c#, infragistics

My scenario is:
I have Infragistics Tab Control and i put windows forms TableLayoutOutPanel inside it dyanamically.

So how to get TableLayoutOutPanel from Infragistics Tab Control??
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

When adding controls they are added to an [UltraTabPageControl](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTabPageControl_members.html) and this like any other Control has a [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) method that allows you to find child controls by Name.